# Communication between Google Chrome extension and My Web application

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a web application. Now I am building an extension for it.
I am now trying to authenticate user. I am saving authentication token in cookies and local storage.. 
First of all Is it a good approach to save tokens in local storage? 
2nd how can I extract that token from my extension.

Comment: A *content script* in your extension can access web site's localStorage directly.

Comment: How? Can you please give an example

Comment: There are lots of examples which you can easily find yourself.